# Much as... so.. structure?

Tags: word-usage

**Much as in the 1970s when clubby Keynesianism gave way to Milton Friedman’s austere monetarism, and in the 1990s when central banks were given their independence, so the pandemic marks the start of a new era.**

Does "much as" mean "just as" here? If so, what does "much" mean here?
Is there a " much as...so...." structure？

Thank you!

Comment: A bit of shuffling will make this simpler; "The pandemic marks the start of a new era, much as in the 1970s when clubby Keynesianism gave way to Milton Friedman’s austere monetarism, and in the 1990s when central banks were given their independence."

Comment: I was about to ask how can we rearrange the setence, so that it can be understood easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a short form of 'in much the same way as'  which means 'in a similar manner'.

It doesn't quite mean 'just as' because 'just as' means that the parallel is exact whereas the supposed new era started by the pandemic has started in a different way from the new eras started by the adoption of Friedman's monetarism and bank liberalisation.

You could say that the bank liberalisation era started 'just as' the monetarist era started because they were the result of deliberate policy changes by government driven by political theory and you could, perhaps, say that the era started by the pandemic started 'just as' the era started by the financial crisis of 2008 did because both were ushered in by unplanned events which, though foreseeable in principle, could not have been accurately predicted in terms of their timing.

Don't forget that there is another meaning of the phrase 'just as', which is *not* the one discussed above. It can also mean 'at the same moment'. For instance "Just as the train set off I realised I had left my briefcase on the platform." You cannot use 'much as' to indicate a less accurate coincidence of timing but you can use it to indicate roughly parallel, rather than exactly parallel, causation.

Comment: Yes, this is where I do not understand. Usually, when coming across shortened phrases like this one, I cannot get the meaning by looking at a dictionary. In this context, "Much as" in dictionaries is defined as "even though", or "although”. I think I just need to read more.